# Import sqlalchemy import *,SSHOperator and BranchPythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow, python-import, python-module, python-datetime

I am writing a python script. On top tried importing some modules from the packages.
I am confused with these lines. Can some one explain in simple terms, the "Meaning" of these lines?

I have just written these lines of code. I am stuck at understanding the difference between 'variable' and 'Variable' with a capital V.

Comment: Please clarify your specific question or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell what you're asking. Also check out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: "Import" simply tells python to go and find additional libraries/functionality that you can only use after that import.  e.g. SQLAlchemy  gives the ability to craete and run SQL queries using python style language.